APIM can not route traffic to Azure app service trough private endpoint
My Goal: Communicate APIM and azure app service using private endpoint. No exposure via public internet.
Current setUp: i have a APIM standard stv2 and i created for it a private endpoint in a subnet A , also i have a app service that i disabled its public access and created for it a private endpoint in the same subnet A (Al ressources exist in the same region west eu).
a dns zone is created for the app service and linked to the virtal network.
here is a screenshot on the current configuration:
Here is the dns record of type A

Here is the network linked

Here is the dns server is the virtual network is set to Default

And in APIM am using this default link of the app service that am doubting to use it or use the private link (anyway both did not work for me)

And about netwrk security group associated with the subnet am alowing port 443,80 and 8080 for inboud and outbound from any source *
and also in the subnet  am alowing the private endpoint communication

Any solution or idea why i still get forbidden access from the apim and still can not communicate with the app service

In general, private endpoints in APIM doesn't support outbound configurations so it is not exactly possible to connect APIM with a web app if private endpoints are enabled. @bouthayna hamdi

what if i route using routing tables?

What kind of routing you wanted to use. @bouthayna hamdi

@bouthaynahamdi, do you use default NSG-rules or have you set any custom rules? This configuration should work just fine, as long as the Private-DNS is resolved correctly.


APIM can not route traffic to Azure app service trough private endpoint

Currently, outbound traffic is not supported for API Management when using a private endpoint connection. You can follow the MS DOC for more details.

You can use the internal Virtual Network model to establish a secure connection from API Management to an App Service by following the MS DOC
Here is the PowerShell command to create APIM in internal mode
New-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName "Automation_RG" -Location "East US" -Name "pstestinternalvnet2-new" -Organization "Contoso" -AdminEmail "admin@contoso.com" -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork -VpnType "Internal" -Sku "Premium"


Reference:  Create an API Management instance inside a virtual network
Create a new Azure API Management instance by using the Azure portal
Stack link answered by me for same issue

Hi @@bouthaynahamdi, I hope this helps you to resolve your problem? If not, please leave a comment here and I will try to help you.
